# Where does the purely UI-related javascript go in a Durandal view?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

I'm playing with a Durandal-based SPA, and following their convention of having a 'views' and 'viewmodels' the basic functionality is working fine. I.e. using `somepage.html` & `somepage.js`.

However, when adding more interactive UI elements (e.g. a collapsible accordian, or informative popups), where should the javascript that handles those events go? It doesn't 'smell' right to put it in the `somepage.js` viewmodel file - that's for the... *view model*!

From a best-practice perspective, would it be better to have a script block in my `somepage.html` file? E.g.

```
<section>
    <!- html markup and data-binding goes here>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- UI-only Javascript goes here>
</script>
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: The javascript for HTML should be handled by **bindings** or **widgets**. If you want a knockout accordian, google it. Popups could be handled by the viewmodel in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been struggling with this, too, and I agree that putting view related stuff in the viewModel smells. The reason I needed to do what you're speaking of was to [attach a delegated event handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) - this can't be done using a custom binding or a widget as has been suggested.

The best solution that a colleague and I came up with was to propagate the `viewAttached` event from the viewModel, and to listen for the event in a "view file".

Using a view named "awesome" as an example, we're using a naming convention like this:

- **View Model** - viewmodels/awesome.js
- **View** - views/awesome.html
- **View File** - views/awesome.html.js

Here's a simplified version of what we're doing.

**viewmodels/awesome.js:**

```
define([
    "durandal/app",
    "durandal/system",

    // require the view file; note we don't need a reference to it,
    // we just need to make sure it's loaded
    "views/myView.html"
],

function (app, sys) {
    var viewModel = {
        // whatever
    };

    viewModel.viewAttached = function(view) {
        // Create a namespace for the event
        var eventNamespace = sys.getModuleId(viewModel)
            .replace("viewmodels", "")
            .replace("/", ".");

        // This will evaluate to 'awesome.viewAttached'
        var eventName = eventNamespace + ".viewAttached";

        // Trigger the event and pass the viewModel and the view
        app.trigger(eventName, viewModel, view);
    };

    return viewModel;
});
```

**views/awesome.html.js:**

```
define([
    "durandal/app"
],

function (app) {
    var module = {
        viewAttached: function(viewModel, view) {
            // do your thing! make sure any selectors you use use the view as the parent selector,
            // because you're not guaranteed that your view is in the DOM (only that it's attached
            // to its parent).
            var $submit = $("#submit", view);
        }
    };

    // wire-up
    app.on("awesome.viewAttached", module.viewAttached);

    // export
    return module;
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll still have to wrap my head around how the delegated event handlers work, but this seems to be an elegant solution that follows existing structural conventions. Thanks!

Comment: The delegated event handlers let you attach an event on a parent node, which can then pick up events for child nodes. e.g. if you had a container full of buttons, rather than attaching a "click" event handler for every button, you could attach a single event handler on the container which listens for any "click" event coming from a child button. Very handy!

Answer (score 3):

Your pure GUI javascript elements should be bound to the UI by html data attributes.  For instance a bootstrap accordian would have the following html [(Bootstrap Documentation here)](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
.......
```

and your bootstrap javascript file referenced at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

viewAttached is quite a dangerous little thing... its tempting to put all JS code in there... but its not ideal. The one little quirk i found is that in nested view models

Parent
Step 1 (Child 1)
Step 2 (Child 2)

Parents Switches (child1 <--> child2)

If the parent does manipulation of the child views (swap from Child 1 to Child 2) viewAttached will not fire properly on the children (the DOM is not yet available at that point in time) and since the parent is already attached it wont run viewAttached on the parent either!

So suddenly you find all your JS modules will stop working, you then have to do ko customBindings for the elements that need to be modified by external JS.